# Converting LAS 1.4 to 1.2

Tags: dem, convert, lidar, las, free-software

LIDAR files were released for major part of Slovenia few months back in zlas format. Decompressed LAS format is 1.4 version. I have tried many options how to generate DEMs and had some success in programs and tools but unfortunately they were all trial versions of license pay versions.

Problem is that I can't open and generate DEMs of LAS version 1.4 in many open and free tools (such as MCC-Lidar).

Can you help me converting LAS from 1.4 to 1.2 in some free tool? Or if it is any other way for LAS 1.4.

Comment: Could you make a list about what free tools you have tried so far and which LAS versions they support by the documentation and by your own experiments? Others can then improve your list.

Comment: Linking related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155567/converting-las-files-from-version-1-2-to-1-3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For converting to las 1.2 from las 1.4, [PDAL's translate command](http://www.pdal.io/apps.html#translate-command) is an option:

```
pdal translate --writers.las.minor_version=2 input-las14.las output-las12.las
```

[LAStools](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools) can also do the job:

```
las2las -i input-las14.las -set_version 1.2 -o output-las12.las
```

In general, las 1.4 support is patchy among free and open-source las-aware software, e.g. [liblas](http://www.liblas.org/) doesn't handle it.

Comment: You solved my problem. I tried before with las2las tool in QGIS, but simply didn't have any success in finding the right place to insert line you posted. I downloaded las2las.exe and it worked. Big thanks!